# undefined method whe using strftime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strftime

I'm new to rails and I stumbled upon an issue.

I'm trying to build this note/meetings app and I'm getting **undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass** error when using strftime. I'm using simple_calendar.

Here's where the error it's comming from:

```
<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= meeting.starts_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y,%l:%M %p") %>
</div>
```

On the flip side, the strftime method does work when called here for example:

```
<li id="m-time"><%= meeting.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %></li>
```

Help?

Comment: Presumably, `meeting.starts_at` is nil. You probably want to put a `nil` check in to guard against calling `strftime` on a nil object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `meeting.starts_at` is `nil`. Your other call work because `meeting.create_at` is a date, which responds to the `strftime` message, as opposed to `nil`, which does not.

How to prevent `meeting.starts_at` from being `nil` depends on where the `meeting` value comes from. Maybe you want to add better validation so a meeting cannot be created without a `starts_at` date. Or, if having no starting date is valid, you should add an `<% if meeting.starts_at %>` `<% end %>` block around the part where you try to access `meeting.starts_at` so that nothing is rendered if there is no starting date. You could also add an `<% else %>` block to render something different if there is no meeting start date.

Answer (score 0):

Issue: `meeting.starts_at` is `nil`. You can not call that method on `nil`.

Solution:

1. Ensure that you have either a method that returns a non-nil value or an attribute with the name of `starts_at` in the Meeting model, with the validation `presence: true` to ensure that non-nil value is not stored in it.
2. Use `meeting.starts_at&.strftime("%B %e, %Y,%l:%M %p")` to avoid crash in case if `starts_at` is `nil`